# How to referesh the primary tab in console after sending the email using custom button

Tags: javascript, email, custom-button, ajax-toolkit, refresh

I have a custom button in lead detail page which is used to send an email. After sending the email , i am updating the status from New to In progress. Everything is working fine. But after sending the email , i have to again manually refresh the tab to see the email sent in the activity history. it is not displaying it after click on send button in the email sending page.
Here is the code of custom button.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/36.0/integration.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")} 
if(sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
if ('{!Lead.OwnerId}' != '{!User.Id}'){
alert("{!$Label.SFA_SendEmail_NotAuthorized}");
}else if (('{!Lead.Brand__c}'=='RENAULT')){
    if (('{!Lead.IsContactCallSucessfull__c}'==true))
    {
    sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function (result)
{
sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id , '{!$Site.BaseUrl}/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={!Lead.Id}&p26=25003082@crm.renault.fr &template_id={!$Label.PDQ_SuccessTemplate}',true,'',null);
});
}
else 
{
sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function (result)
{
sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id , '{!$Site.BaseUrl}/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={!Lead.Id}&p26=25003082@crm.renault.fr &template_id={!$Label.PDQ_FailureTemplate}',true,'',null);
});
}
}
else if (('{!Lead.Brand__c}'=='DACIA' )){
if (('{!Lead.IsContactCallSucessfull__c}'==true))
    {
        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function (result)
{
sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id , '{!$Site.BaseUrl}/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={!Lead.Id}&p26=25003082@crm.dacia.fr &template_id={!$Label.PDQ_SuccessTemplate}',true,'',null);
});
}
else
{
sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function (result)
{
sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id , '{!$Site.BaseUrl}/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={!Lead.Id}&p26=25003082@crm.dacia.fr &template_id={!$Label.PDQ_FailureTemplate}',true,'',null);
});
}
}
}
sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(showTabId);
var showTabId = function showTabId(result) 
        {
            var tabId = result.id;
            alert('Primary Tab IDs: primaryTabId ' + tabId );
            sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(tabId , true, refreshSuccess);
        };

        var refreshSuccess = function refreshSuccess(result) 
        {
            //Report whether refreshing the primary tab was successful
            if (result.success == true) 
            {
                alert('Primary tab refreshed successfully');
            } 
            else 
            {
                alert('Primary did not refresh');
            }
        };
```

Comment: can you please try once this solution http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/100876/18731

Comment: Tried ratan . still it is the same

Comment: Checked that .. no error is coming

Comment: I have edited the question and you can see the updated code now.